# Смена текущей недели по свайпу

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема, есть 4 лейбла на которые выводится информация :
1  - текущая дата.
2  - номер недели в году.
3  - день начала недели.
4 - день конча недели.
Нужно чтобы по свайпу в лево или право, менялся номер недели .
Подскажите как это сделать, или где посмотреть .

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение соотв. уровню вопроса:

1. Где-то во `viewDidLoad` контроллера с вашими пресловутыми лейблами:

   ```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandler:)]; 
   leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandler:)];
   rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
   ```
2. Не забудьте здесь же в этом же контроллере реализовать обработку свайпов:
3. `(void) leftSwipeHandler { }`
4. `(void) rightSwipeHandler { }`

Answer (score 3):

Добавляете обработку свайпов и все:

1. Добавляете Swipe Gestrure Recognizer во View (где у вас Label)
2. Выделяете Swipe (как на скрине)
3. Кидаете "делегата" на view
4. Добавляете Action
5. Обрабатываете экшен

Вот примерно на картинке:[image]

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.